# Не сохраняется том при удалении контейнера в Docker

Tags: docker

В dockerfile:
VOLUME ["/data"]
когда контейнер запущен в фоне, то том виден по команде: docker volume ls, а когда контейнер удаляю, то и том пропадает. Разве тома не сохраняются после удаления контейнера? Зачем вообще команда VOLUME  в dockerfile, если мы можем смонтировать через -v при запуске контейнера.?

Comment: Приложите конфиг запуска контейнера

Comment: docker run --rm -it my_image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте для запуска ключ `--rm`, он удаляет все связанное с контейнером сразу, как только он прекращает свою работу.

Преимущества ключа `-v` в команде `docker run` в том, что вы можете создавать именованные томы, например:

```
docker run -v container_data:/data
```

Запустив команду `docker volume ls` вы увидите в списке том с названием `container_data`

Про `docker volume` почитать можно в [оф. документации](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: а зачем тогда помещать volume в dockerfile. сразу при запуске монтируем ...

Comment: @and_noob, не заметил ключ `--rm`, обновил ответ.

Comment: В документации написано, что просто удаляет контейнер...

Comment: @and_noob, вы можете сами позапускать с этим ключом и без него и посмотреть на результат. В чем проблема?

Comment: все правильно, только неочевидно зачем в dockerfile этот volume. где-то туплю

Comment: @and_noob, погуглить можно ведь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163036/difference-between-volume-declaration-in-dockerfile-and-v-as-docker-run-paramet

Comment: спасибо вам, плохо искал